# How to load Ajax Site Wide?

Tags: 8, theming, ajax

I am trying to open a webform in a modal window through following link, which works fine when I am logged in, but when I logout it simply stops working

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:600}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/form/call-back">Get a Call Back</a>
```

It seems like we need to load ajax on pages where we want to use this link, so I want to know how can I load ajax sitewide.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`hook_page_attachments_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.4.x) like so:

```
function MODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'drupal.ajax';
}
```

The same hook can be implemented in a theme if that makes more sense.